# How to remove similar combinations from set of values

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

How to remove same combinations from set of values

- A B 2
- B A 2
- A C 1
- C A 1
- B D 3
- D B 3

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC1Wk.png)

I need to get

- A B 2
- A C 1
- B D 3

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tceaC.png)

as the output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide some code to show if you had tried and read the page on how to format.

Comment: How do you define a combination? You seem to have only letters. Is a combination a pair of letters followed by a number? Do you have to preserve order of elements? Do you have to preserve order of letters in pairs?

Comment: Please do not use links but include all relevant information directly in your question. See the how to ask page for details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

First you need to store the data in Dataframe
you can apply drop duplicates on your example but it won't be work on large dataset because,here we are droping the repeated  values of Z column & we are not followed any order.
df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['Z'])